# Magento 2 : Custom product type module update

Tags: magento2, module, upgrade

I have a module that was defining a custom product type: **MyPT1**

I added a second custom product type **(MyPT2)** using the same module.

But When I create a MyPT2 product in the backend, the price is not present.
I Think that it is due to the fact that **InstallData.php** is not run during **setup:upgrade** as the module was already installed.
I then would like to create a **UpgradeData.php** but I don't know how to create it correctly.

Here is my **InstallData.php**

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class InstallData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function install(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

        $fieldList = [
            'price',
            'special_price',
            'special_from_date',
            'special_to_date',
            'minimal_price',
            'cost',
            'tier_price',
            'weight',
        ];

        foreach ($fieldList as $field) {
            $applyTo = explode(
                ',',
                $eavSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $field, 'apply_to')
            );
            if (!in_array(\Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type\MyPT1::TYPE_CODE, $applyTo)) {
                $applyTo[] = \Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type\MyPT1::TYPE_CODE;
                $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                    $field,
                    'apply_to',
                    implode(',', $applyTo)
                );
            }

            if (!in_array(\Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type\MyPT2::TYPE_CODE, $applyTo)) {
                $applyTo[] = \Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type\MyPT2::TYPE_CODE;
                $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                        $field,
                        'apply_to',
                        implode(',', $applyTo)
                        );
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your help,

Answer (score 0):

This one should work:

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Setup;

use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\InstallDataInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleContextInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;

class UpgradeData implements InstallDataInterface
{
    protected $eavSetupFactory;

    public function __construct(EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory)
    {
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
    }

    public function upgrade(ModuleDataSetupInterface $setup, ModuleContextInterface $context)
    {
        $setup->startSetup();

        if (version_compare($context->getVersion(), '1.0.1', '<')) {

            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);

            $fieldList = [
                'price',
                'special_price',
                'special_from_date',
                'special_to_date',
                'minimal_price',
                'cost',
                'tier_price',
                'weight',
            ];

            foreach ($fieldList as $field) {
                $applyTo = explode(
                    ',',
                    $eavSetup->getAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, $field, 'apply_to')
                );
                if (!in_array(\Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type\MyPT1::TYPE_CODE, $applyTo)) {
                    $applyTo[] = \Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type\MyPT1::TYPE_CODE;
                    $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                        $field,
                        'apply_to',
                        implode(',', $applyTo)
                    );
                }

                if (!in_array(\Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type\MyPT2::TYPE_CODE, $applyTo)) {
                    $applyTo[] = \Vendor\Module\Model\Product\Type\MyPT2::TYPE_CODE;
                    $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
                            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
                            $field,
                            'apply_to',
                            implode(',', $applyTo)
                            );
                }
            }
        }

        $setup->endSetup();
    }
}
```